# What is a minimum set of math operators that can generate all calculations?

Tags: math, computer-science

I am thinking about a minimal instruction set CPU, say ten or fewer opcodes.  I want to find the smallest set of math opcodes that can still perform any general-purpose function.

For example, in logic the operators AND, OR, NOT are redundant.  You can calculate any function with the other two, so a minimum set of logical operators needs only two.

For arithmetic functions, could I get by with two opcodes, perhaps ADD and bit-wise invert?
(assume a carry bit and a jump-on-carry instruction).

With ADD and BITINV I can do subtraction without an explicit SUB operator.  Multiplication and division are easy extensions from addition and subtraction.  SHL is multiply by two, and SHR is divide by two.

To cover logic and arithmetic it looks like AND, BITINV, ADD are a complete minimum set.  Did I miss anything?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [Wikipedia article on minimal instruction set computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_instruction_set_computer)

Comment: I found that yesterday.  That was interesting, and inspired me to find a simple instruction set with more than two instructions, but less than sixteen.  There is an architecture with a single instruction: ADD-with-conditional-JMP.

Comment: And because it's Turing complete that means you can perform all the arithmetic operations. So it seems like you've already got your answer as to the minimal set of instructions for math operations.

Comment: for logic operators you can do anything with just NAND or just by NOR so you do not need 2 instructions for that. also you need register and stack specific operations ...

Answer (score 2):

You probably also need to include control instructions like conditionals and jumps to make your instruction set Turing complete (or maybe your instruction set should be able to construct all [computable functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function)).

For example, in your question,

> Multiplication and division are easy extensions from addition and
>   subtraction

This is not true without the notion of loops and conditionals (consider, e.g. the Euclidean algorithm for division). You have to have loops somewhere to make a division.

Comment: You are right.  An overflow/carry flag is needed with the ADD instruction, and a Jump-on-condition opcode as well.  Load/Store instructions are needed to move the data around.  The whole processor could be this simple:  ADD, BITINV, AND, JCC, LD, STO